# Camera view occluded by robot body, how to deal for SLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my mobile robot, I have a RGBD camera(zed) which even at the lowest resolution/fov setting, captures part of the robot body. When performing visual SLAM using RTabMap unfortunately the body is interpreted as part of the environment.

Be sides just cropping the camera stream, which adds latency I'd like to avoid, is there any other way to deal with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349659/camera-view-occluded-by-robot-body,-how-to-deal-for-slam?/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option is to pre-filter the camera data for robot parts based on your URDF model. Examples of packages that provide such functionality are

- https://github.com/blodow/realtime_urdf_filter
- MoveIt's depth self filter, see  [for instance here](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html#yaml-configuration-file-depth-map).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1